# Encrypted List items

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

I have a `SharePoint` `2010` site that requires people to track their weights in a `List`. Apparently, people are very sensitive about this subject, and want their information hidden from everybody. However these values still need to be tracked by other items on the site.

I realize that you can set certain site permissions (read/write/etc), but is there a way to encrypt certain list items in `SharePoint` `2010` so that it is hidden from everyone except the owner but still have them be available for computational use?

Answer (score 2):

There is no encryption option on a list level. Lists have item level security built into them by simply going to the List Settings and clicking on the Advanced settings. From there you can set the Read option to Read items that were created by the user and the Create and Edit option to Create and edit items that were created by the current user. Also set the search option to No.

This will prevent other users, except for those with manage list permissions, to view other people's information.